# Set width of div relatively to width of browser window

Tags: css

How can I set the `width` property of a `div` so that it is always a percentage of the browser window's width?

For example,

- when the width of the browser window is 1920px, the `div`'s width is 1536px (80%)
- when the width of the browser window is 1600px, the `div`'s width is 1280px (80%)

and so forth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a wrapper div and set it equal to 100% of the browser width, then put the desired div and set it to `width:80%`. This will allow you to center your desired div too. (use `margin:0 auto` for this.)

Here's a JSFiddle with a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lwpr/

Comment: then how can I do the 100%?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to attach the JSFiddle. You would make the desired div a child of a `wrapper` div, and set `width:100%;`. So basically, you would end up with this: `<div id="wrapper" style="width:100%;"><div id="desired" style="width:80%;"></div></div>`

Answer (score 3):

vw: Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_vw

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
.main
{width:100%;
margin-left:auto; 

margin-right:auto;


}
.content
{
width:80%;
margin-left:auto; 

margin-right:auto;

}
```

Comment: ^ i tried that but i am unable to set the width/height of the divs automatically according to browser width/height : https://codepen.io/spike321/pen/LYVqavZ